# Не работает register_next_step_handler в telebot sqlite3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

**Как заносить информацию в бд через сообщение боту?**

**main.py**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['addorder'])
def addorder(message: types.Message):
    addordermsg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер заказа')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(addordermsg, addordertext)

def addordertext(message: types.Message):
    db.add_order(message.text)
    addstatusmsg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Теперь введите статус заказа')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(addstatusmsg, addstatustext)

def addstatustext(message: types.Message):
    db.add_status(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Готово!')
```

**database.py**

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(db_file, check_same_thread=False)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def add_order(self, order_number):
        with self.con:
            return self.cur.execute("UPDATE orders SET order_number = ?", (order_number,))

    def add_status(self, status):
        with self.con:
            return self.cur.execute("UPDATE orders SET status = ?", (status,))
```

Comment: Первое, что бросается в глаза "UPDATE orders SET status = ?" , а где WHERE? Какую запись Вы хотите UPDATE?

Comment: Cursor надо создавать перед использованием, а не общий.  with self.con.cursor() as cur: cur.execute("UPDATE orders SET status = ? where id=?", (status,id,)) self.con.commit()

Comment: db.add_order(message.text) а что тогда тут записывать в id?

Comment: Мне сложно сказать, таблиц-то Вы не предоставили

Comment: UPDATE orders SET status = ? where order_number=?" Ну и меняете status для нужного order_number

Comment: `Database.add_order() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status'` Оно просит сразу номер и статус вводить, как я понял, но мне надо чтобы они по очереди добавлялись через register_next_step_handler

Comment: Сохраняйте в контексте (context) эти значения и если их набралось два, то update. Не понимаю, зачем Вам order_number менять ("UPDATE orders SET order_number = ?" where order_number=?) ? У Вас, по идее, order_number - primary key должен быть. Ещё не хватает в таблице user_id

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как context должен тут работать. И зачем мне user_id?

Comment: Как Вы понимаете, кому принадлежит order_number ? Распишите в вопросе, что Вы хотите сделать - стала не понятна Ваша затея :)

Comment: обновил описание вопроса, надеюсь теперь будет более понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для админа:

```
def add_order(self, order_number):
    with self.con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO orders VALUES (?,'')",(order_number,))
```

Comment: спасибо, работает